# Xcode, how do I add another target for my app, without duplicate / new?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to add a new device target for my app.
Ideally I'd like to use duplicate and change the device.
But I haven't seen how to do this.

Adding a new target gives me loads of new files, none of which I need and there's lots of settings I'd need to copy from my other targets.

Is there something I'm missing?, it seems like an obvious missing feature.

Comment: If I duplicate a target that's set for iPhone, then go to the General tab for that target, it lets me change the setting for the Devices drop menu to iPad or Universal.  Are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Maybe there are too many differences?  (It doesn't let me choose OS X either.)

Comment: @PhillipMills yep, doing the add new route there's tonnes of settings and I don't need the additional project files.